# Using a HOC with a react-navigation Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

My application makes use of the react-navigation library for routing, but now I have a requirement where I want to show a modal window over only the routes belonging to the TabNavigator. I thought this would work if I created a Higher Order Component and used this to wrap the TabNavigator but this doesn't seem to work.

So what would be the correct way to add functionality to a react-navigation Navigator?

**TabRoutes.js**

This works fine without the provider, but the routes are unreachable as soon as I add the provider to the TabNavigator.

```
import myProvider from './providers/myProvider';

const TabRoutes = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Main: {screen: HomeStack},
  Moments: {screen: MomentStack},
  Settings: {screen: SettingsRoutes}
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Main'
});

export default myProvider(TabRoutes);
```

**Routes.js**

The TabNavigator is part of a SwitchNavigator, but only the routes of the tabs should be able to display the modal.

```
import TabRoutes from './routes/TabRoutes';

const AppRoutes = createSwitchNavigator({
  Loading: LoadingScreen,
  Auth: AuthStack,
  App: TabRoutes,
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Loading'
});
```

**myProvider.js**

```
const myProvider = (wrappedComponent) => {

  class extends React.Component {
    render (
      <View>
        <WrappedComponent {...this.props}>
        <MyModal visible={...}>
          ... // rest of modal
        </MyModal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default myProvider;
```

Comment: Your best bet is probably to create a new Tab Navigator, using react-navigation-tabs/dist/navigators/createBottomTabNavigator.js as a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested, but I would try this next:

**TabRoutes.js**

```
import myProvider from './providers/myProvider';

const TabRoutes = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Main: {screen: myProvider(HomeStack)},
    Moments: {screen: myProvider(MomentStack)},
    Settings: {screen: myProvider(SettingsRoutes)}
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Main'
});

export default TabRoutes;
```

...as surely it's the screen components which you want wrapping, rather than the entire of `TabRoutes`?

Comment: It is the same result, because the screens of the TabNavigator are all StackNavigators themselves. Off course I could add the provider to each and every screen component, but I have over 30 screens so I was looking for a way to optimise ;-) Will upvote your answer though, since it would definitely be possible to add the provider to all individual screens.

Comment: It was a fairly quick first guess, I totally get the issue now. I should've probably commented instead, I appreciate the upvote though as I'm pretty new to React and happy that my answer kinda makes sense, even if it doesn't work :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.